Javascript logic for Google Apps Script (Google Sheet) not working as intended
I have a google sheet that i am trying to search, match, and then auto-populate some data to.
Here is the google sheet layout

 Here is the lookup table layout
 
I wrote some javascript code to try to search cell A2 for a keyword, match it to a value in the lookup table, grab the corresponding data, and then populate it 1 row down, and 1 column right of the keyword. It should repeat this checking every 7th cell in column A until there are no more. Currently, my code works for the first keyword, and then inputs the data incorrectly for the remaining keywords.
function FindItemAndPopulate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Item Autofill");
  var keywordRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A");
  var keywords = keywordRange.getValues();
  var lastRowA = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i += 7) { // Increment by 7 to check every 7th row
    var keyword = keywords[i][0];

    if (keyword !== "") {
      var searchData = sheet.getRange("M2:M" + lastRowA).getValues();
      var rowIndex = -1;

      for (var j = 0; j < searchData.length; j++) {
        if (searchData[j][0] === keyword) {
          rowIndex = j + 2; // Adjust index for row offset due to starting from row 2
          break;
        }
      }

      if (rowIndex !== -1) {
        var rowData = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 14, 1, 5).getValues(); // Get data from columns N to R
        var valuesToPopulate = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < rowData[0].length; k++) {
          valuesToPopulate.push([rowData[0][k] !== "" ? rowData[0][k] : ""]);
        }

        sheet.getRange(rowIndex + 1, 2, 1, 5).setValues([valuesToPopulate]); // Populate data into the next row and 1 column right
      } else {
        sheet.getRange("B" + (i + 2) + ":F" + (i + 2)).clearContent(); // Clear corresponding row if no match found
      }
    } else {
      sheet.getRange("B" + (i + 2) + ":F" + (i + 2)).clearContent(); // Clear corresponding row if keyword is empty
    }
  }
}

I believe I made a mistake somewhere with the index of the keyword not being in the correct scope or not being properly updated, but I cannot figure out where. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is a photo of the result

of the code and a video of code execution
Edit as requested:
Here is the [link to the google document]|Removed since it is not needed anymore| Note: The relevant page is titled "Item Autofill"
here is the photo of intended output:

with the part that is relevant highlighted (the rest is handled elsewhere) and a video of me manually doing what the code should do

I also included a tab called Expected Output that shows what the table should look like after the code has ran- the red text is the part that the code i have posted about manages, the rest is handled elsewhere, so only focus on the red parts

You need to work this out with the debugger.

Add some console.log at the start of loop and control flow blocks. Then run your script and check the console to see the flow of your function. This would give you a much better understanding of which block of code is being executed.

@AbrarHossain Thank you, i was able to pinpoint the problem doing this - when i tried to use the debugger it was timing out before i could find the problem - the code was using the keyword location from the data table, NOT from the source table as it should have been - i have fixed the code now and will add it in a comment and mark it as solved

I was able to find the problem by isolating it using console.log statements - the code was putting the data in rows with the row number coming from the keyword match location of the search table instead of the source table - i fixed it by adding the x variable and using that instead of rowIndex
function FindItemAndPopulate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Item Autofill");
  var keywordRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A");
  var keywords = keywordRange.getValues();
  var lastRowA = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i += 7) { // Increment by 7 to check every 7th row
    var keyword = keywords[i][0];
    if (keyword !== "") {
      var searchData = sheet.getRange("M2:M" + lastRowA).getValues();
      var rowIndex = -1;

      for (var j = 0; j < searchData.length; j++) {
        if (searchData[j][0] === keyword) {
          rowIndex = j + 2; // Adjust index for row offset due to starting from row 2 EDIT: this is the problem variable in question - do not use
          x = i + 2; // this is the correct index we want
          break;
        }
      }

      if (rowIndex !== -1) {
        var rowData = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 14, 1, 5).getValues(); // Get data from columns N to R
        var valuesToPopulate = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < rowData[0].length; k++) {
          valuesToPopulate.push([rowData[0][k] !== "" ? rowData[0][k] : ""]);
        }
        sheet.getRange(x + 1, 2, 1, 5).setValues([valuesToPopulate]); // Populate data into the next row and 1 column right
      } else {
        sheet.getRange("B" + (i + 2) + ":F" + (i + 2)).clearContent(); // Clear corresponding row if no match found
      }
    } else {
      sheet.getRange("B" + (i + 2) + ":F" + (i + 2)).clearContent(); // Clear corresponding row if keyword is empty
    }
  }
}


Its an especially overlooked mistake because i have the correct logic in the clear statements (i+2) but for some reason decided to use rowIndex(j+2) for the actual data location ... I put the data in the wrong location but clear the actual location I wanted

I think if you adjust rowIndex = j + 2;  like this then this comparison if (rowIndex !== -1) { must change to if(rowIndex !== 1 but without understanding what you are trying to accomplish I can't take it any further.

can you elaborate on what information you need to understand what im trying to accomplish? I included all the information that is relevant to the problem including the google sheet in question, the template layout, the expected result, the actual result, and the code - what else should i include to clarify?

i have included a video of the codes incorrect execution in addition to a video of me manually doing what the code should do - i think that should clarify its goal

If you could produce a [mcve] so that I can reproduce the unique problem that you are having then you can be fairly well assured to get an answer.  Of course, it's often the case that in your attempt to produce such an example  you often end up solving the problem on your own and that ends up being even more beneficial to you.  It's difficult for me to answer the question because I do not understand what your problem is and I  don't have the environment to test it in and I also don't wish to expose my email to you inorder to access your spreadsheet.

That is understandable - I have solved the issue and posted the answer. In regard to the spreadsheet access, if that is a common occurrence then you can make a separate email for accessing them - The account I shared it from is an account I made just to share it, for similar reasons.
